# Text processing with Python

Tags: python, text-processing

I need to extract 1,500,000 out of 25,000,000 records and group them.

The groups and the UUIDs of the records to extract are defined in a separate file (200MB) with the following format:

```
>Cluster 0
0   70nt, >90ec66e4-c038-41f0-a553-c94864cf3958... at +/80.00%
1   88nt, >2d45d336-a0f4-4eca-8577-b950e11bb4cf... *
2   70nt, >6f6ad8f1-0cfb-4e57-8962-366cd749fa3f... at +/82.86%
>Cluster 1
0   74nt, >5f584468-a231-416d-9156-ff68e11ee096... *
>Cluster 2
0   74nt, >7f584468-a231-416d-9156-ff68e11ee096... *
1   79nt, >f7884902-51d4-48e1-88a3-9adc0bd0f2cd... at +/86.08%
```

Here's my function for parsing it:

```py
def clstr_parse(filename):
    clstr = None
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                if clstr:
                    yield clstr
                clstr = []
            else:
                uuid = line.split()[2][1:37]
                clstr.append(uuid)
    if clstr:
        yield clstr
```

Then I use it to extract the "groups" (list of UUIDs) that contain more than one UUID:

```py
groups = [grp for grp in clstr_parse('file.clstr') if len(grp) >= 2]
```

And define a `dict` (with the UUIDs as keys) for storing the records during their extraction:

```py
records = {uuid: None for grp in groups for uuid in grp}
```

The file (30GB) from which I need to extract the records is in the following format (the columns are <kbd>TAB</kbd>-delimited):

```
@something ...some_defs...
@...more_things...
92fa0cdf-9e1b-4f83-b6e0-ca35885bfdbd    16  ...more_fields...
2d45d336-a0f4-4eca-8577-b950e11bb4cf    16  ...more_fields...
2d45d336-a0f4-4eca-8577-b950e11bb4cf    2064    ...more_fields...
f7884902-51d4-48e1-88a3-9adc0bd0f2cd    0   ...more_fields...
90ec66e4-c038-41f0-a553-c94864cf3958    16  ...more_fields...
6f6ad8f1-0cfb-4e57-8962-366cd749fa3f    0   ...more_fields...
7f584468-a231-416d-9156-ff68e11ee096    16  ...more_fields...
```

I made a function for yielding each record:

```py
def sam_parse(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('@'):
                pass
            else:
                yield line
                for line in f:
                    yield line
```

Which I use in the extraction process:

```py
for rec in sam_parse('file.sam'):
    (uuid, flag) = rec.split(maxsplit=2)[0:2]
    if uuid in records and int(flag) < 2048:
        records[uuid] = rec[0:-1]

for grp in groups:
    for uuid in grp:
        print(records[uuid])
    print()
```

The problem is that I would expect this program to take less than 10 minutes to complete (tested a similar code in `awk`) but it's been 8 hours that I launched it and it's still running. Is there something wrong with the Python code?

Comment: The `else`-branch in your `sam_parse` function does not make sense to me. Why are you starting another `for line in f` loop inside the outer `for line in f` loop?

Comment: Have you considered using a framework like pandas for this task?

Comment: How long does it take for "clstr_parse()" to run? Is that time reasonable? Is it taking a long time to get the groups or to parse the groups with "sam_parse()"? Trying to nail down what to focus on exactly.

Comment: @treuss It's a remnant of an other version. I kept it because it allows to skip the test of first char once we passed the header.

Comment: `it's been 8 hours that I launched it and it's still running` I would suggest adding progress bars to your loop. This way you can get a rough estimate of lines/second, and then know about how many hours you'll need to wait. Example: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#iterable-based

Comment: @JesseSealand it is `clstr_parse` that is still running; `clstr_parse` only need a few seconds to complete

Comment: If this is a standard file format, have you searched for an existing library to parse it?

Comment: @Fravadona Did you mean "clstr_parse *should* only need a few seconds to complete"? How large is the file? Are you sure you are using the right one?

Comment: @NickODell I guess I'll have to do that; I didn't expect the program to be so desperately slow for such a simple task

Comment: @ThierryLathuille The code works fine with a small dataset; it should also work with the provided samples (I'll test it now)

Comment: I just ran clster_parse on 28 million entries in the rile.clstr file and it finished in 29 seconds. The clstr file was 1.19 GB.

Comment: groups = []

for grp in tqdm(clstr_parse(r'C:\Users\Architect\Desktop\file.clstr')):
    
    if len(grp) >= 2:
        groups.append(grp)

Comment: @Barmar There is indeed a library that can parse the records but using it will require thrice the RAM and a `gc.collect()` at each iteration

Comment: Your list comprehension code just finished it in 22 seconds. Your code seems fine.

Comment: @JesseSealand Thank you for testing it; and sorry, my previous comment was wrong, it is `sam_parse` that is taking a helplessly long time

Comment: Your splitting by tabs "\t" but I don't see any tabs in your sam file data. Are you sure you don't want to split by spaces?

Comment: @JesseSealand I couldn't reproduce the TABs in SO, but there is one TAB between each non-white-space column

Comment: I find there is a 20% speedup if you replace `for line in f: yield line` with `yield from f`.

Comment: @JesseSealand I updated the `split()` call so that it can works with both the provided sample and the real file

Comment: @NickODell That's really good to know

Comment: My computer crashed trying to process the GB files.

Comment: @JesseSealand Sorry about that :-( The program needs to load the selected records in memory in order to group them; it requires not a good amount of RAM

Comment: Some benchmarking shows that `(uuid, flag) = rec.split("\t", maxsplit=2)[0:2]` can be re-written as `uuid, flag, _ = rec.split("\t", maxsplit=2)`, and is about 10% faster that way. (Assuming you always have three splits!)

Comment: @NickODell I'll try it now, along with the `yield from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to process ~2 million records from the sam file in 6 seconds. I did two things, first i removed the second yield statement in the definition such that

```
def sam_parse(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('@'):
                pass
            else:
                yield line
```

Then secondly, I resplit the flag to make sure its an integer value. I kept getting error when I didn't split the flag string a second time.

```
for rec in sam_parse('file.sam'):
    (uuid, flag) = rec.split("    ")[0:2]
    flag = flag.split(" ")[0]
    if uuid in records and int(flag) < 2048:
        records[uuid] = rec[0:-1]
```

Comment: You mean removing the `[0:2]` after `rec.split` and then further split the flag?

Comment: I keep getting errors when trying to convert the flag to an int for some reason, that's why I suggest it.

Comment: Isn't `flag = flag.split(" ")[0]` a no-op? It only does something if there is whitespace in the flag. But the previous line removes whitespace from the first two components of the split.

Comment: Remember that my file has 4 spaces in place of a tab character because I copied from the post.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem was but it works with the `sam_parse` modification. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Your original version wouldn't skip lines starting with @ after the first block. Are there maybe such lines further down in your file?